# What is the correct way to quickly deselecting multiple objects?

Tags: selection-tools

Please refer to the screenshot. I'm trying to deselect some of the pieces on the legs, while keeping the rest of the leg, the armature and the rest of body selected. I've done quite some searches online and all sources say that to deselect an object you either hold shift and click it, or hold shift + alt and click it to pick an object from the menu to exclude it. I tried both and both required that I operate twice for each object, so to deselect all of these I would have to do shift+alt click 40+ times.
[image: deselecting objects]
Is there a way to quickly deselect multiple objects at once?

Comment: You can use circle select, and hold down alt while doing it. Same with border select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly unselect you can use the lasso with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key pressed, so it should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>:

[image]